# Huawei P8 lite 2017 does not receive push notifications

Tags: android, ionic-framework, huawei-mobile-services

I've written an app in Ionic3 that receives some notification.
It does work on every device I tested it on apart from somo Huawei devices as P8 Lite 2017 and Mate 8.

Google told me to set my app as "Protected App" but in these models there is no way to do that. I allowed notifications but nothing works.

I can do that in P8 Lite (2015) and it works.

How can I make it work on Mate 8 and P8 Lite 2017?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

We found the solution.
Even if I uninstall the app, App Data still persist in the phone.
When re-install you should clear data and cache from Settings>App>AppName>Memory, otherwise target_token necessary, for push notifications, won't change!

For new app versions, it's best practice to increment version in config.xml.